# Unable to nest (group) Stackdriver logs outside of AppEngine

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Following this guide: https://medium.com/google-cloud/combining-correlated-log-lines-in-google-stackdriver-dd23284aeb29 I tried to nest two logs using the sample json:

```
{"httpRequest": {"status": 200, "latency": "1.010 s", "requestUrl": "https://example.com/1", "requestMethod": "GET", "remoteIp": "1.2.3.4", "userAgent": "my-user-agent", "responseSize
": 1023}, "logging.googleapis.com/trace": "3dea50fd-0e2e-4bfd-bf61-0ded0f2ff82b", "severity": "INFO"}
{"message": "child message!", "labels": {"name": "child-log"}, "logging.googleapis.com/trace": "3dea50fd-0e2e-4bfd-bf61-0ded0f2ff82b", "severity": "INFO"}
```

Indeed, the requests are grouped - I now have a "show all logs for this trace" button. But they are separate log entries, and not nested like they would be in AppEngine.

How would a structured logging json look like for two entries logged outside of AppEngine that will be nested?

Comment: I followed tutorial you linked and all entries have "Expand nested fields" button. I'm not sure if we're on the same page, can you share more details about your config and environment?

Comment: Did you do it outside of AppEngine, by sending the json output to Stackdriver? I send it using google-fluentd from an AWS box.

Comment: Do you have an AWS VM sending logs to GCP?  
Can you provide more details?

Comment: There is an AWS box with multiple programs, each writing logs in the rich json format to log files. google-fluentd is running on that box, collecting those logs and sending them to stackdriver. When I append the snippet I posted to one of these log files it gets logged fine - just not nested.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how a group of nested logs would look like using the json output format.

Comment: Considering the amount of information required to understand the situation, it'll be best to reach out to [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) or [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/).

Comment: But AWS has nothing to do with this, it might as well be any box at all. All I'm asking for is: how would the log output in json look like, if I wanted to have nested StackDriver logs and used google-fluentd for logging? There is really not that much amount of information required...